# Processing LWGEOM Provider crashes QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-2.18, homebrew

I am trying to use the LWGEOM processing algorithms in QGIS 2.18 running on OS X (El Capitan). I have installed the liblwgeom library (v. 2.1.5) using a Homebrew formula and successfully set its provider path under Processing > Options. When I run the algorithm, QGIS crashes immediately.

What might be causing this crash, and how can I confirm that I've installed the algorithm correctly?

Comment: I hope you've resolved this! I wonder if you could post additional info? What was the path you used? The authors video for the plugin only shows install for windows machines. I have yet to get the path correct enough to crash. ;)
Thanks!

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment on the original question or try posting your own question to GIS SE.